# Filter a pandas data frame based on the count of a column value from the end

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1    col2
1        A
2        B
1        A
2        A
3        B
4        A
5        A
6        A
7        B
8        A
9        B
```

Now I want to filter this data frame and take all the rows till third B from the end, so the data frame will look like,

```
col1     col2
3        B -->third B
4        A
5        A
6        A
7        B -->second B
8        A
9        B -->first B
```

I could do this using a for loop check checking if its B in every iteration, but it will take longer time to execute, looking for some pandas shortcuts to do it in efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cumsum` from numpy to count the nubmer of B's and filter on that:

```
df[np.cumsum(df['col2'] == 'B') >= df['col2'].value_counts()['B'] - 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try`cumsum`

```
out = df[df.col2.eq('B').iloc[::-1].cumsum()<=3].loc[lambda x : x['col2'].eq('B').cumsum()>=1]
Out[41]: 
    col1 col2
4      3    B
5      4    A
6      5    A
7      6    A
8      7    B
9      8    A
10     9    B
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the masking for `col2` whether it's equal to `B`, reverse the masking, call `cumsum`, then get the maximum index where cumsum is equal to 3, then finally take the slice from this index to rest of the dataframe.

```py
>>> df.loc[df['col2'].eq('B').iloc[::-1].cumsum().eq(3).idxmax():]

    col1 col2
4      3    B
5      4    A
6      5    A
7      6    A
8      7    B
9      8    A
10     9    B
```

**PS:** You may want to reset the index if `col1` is the index.